# Inserting element in an arraylist to render empty line

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces on the frontend and populating a `selectOneList` using an arraylist in my backing bean

I want to have the array list separated by *new lines* to make some logical separations

How can I add an element to an `ArrayList` that will be rendered as an *empty line* ?

Comment: Show us some code, what kind of `ArrayList`? Have you tried `yourArrayList.add("")`or `yourArrayList.add(new SelectItem("", ""))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will help you to achieve the functionality you want, that is to enter some empty line in `<p:selectOneListBox>`. Now I am not sure if it is a feature of this component that to squeeze out the empty string. So `""` will not work.

This is a sample managed bean:

```
package app.so.dev.web.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import app.so.dev.web.model.Student;

@ManagedBean(name = "so15350373")
@ViewScoped
public class SO15350373 implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2190171095461884759L;
    private List<Student> students;
    private int selected;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        students.add(new Student(1, "Student 1"));
        students.add(new Student(2, "&nbsp;"));
        students.add(new Student(3, "Student 3"));
        students.add(new Student(4, "&nbsp;"));
        students.add(new Student(5, "Student 5"));
        students.add(new Student(6, "Student 6"));
    }

    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public void setStudents(List<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }

    public int getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelectedStudent(int selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }   
}
```

The `Student` is a simple POJO having two field `id` and `name`. For the sake of brevity, I am not showing this class :P.

And this is the xhtml:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="/WEB-INF/templates/globalTemplate.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="title">15350373</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form>
            <p:selectOneListbox value="#{so15350373.selected}" id="list">
                <f:selectItems value="#{so15350373.students}" var="student" itemLabel="#{student.name}" itemValue="#{student.id}" />
            </p:selectOneListbox>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Comment: You might want to set `escapeItem="false"` on the `<f:selectItems/>` so the browser interprets it properly

Comment: Thanks a lot Tapas ! That worked. Thanks for a great example ! I had tried myarrayList.add("") before but that did not work.

Comment: Kolossus, i did not have to set that attribute to false for the desired effect. Atleast Internet Explorer 9 is fine without it, or that attribute is false by default ! Thanks though !